# What does this goblet icon mean?

Tags: diablo-iii

Upon going through my quests to make I had completed everything, I noticed that some of quests had a strange goblet icon in front of them. What does this mean?

[image]

Comment: It's the active quest.

Comment: The thing is, I see it whenever I select a quest in Act V.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It shows you which step of the quest you are currently on. If you had started the quest and finished the **Giedeon's row** part the cup/trophy would be on **Talk to the Mystic**. That's also why you see it on every starting subquests of every main quest.